# How to debug a Google App Engine app with Java 11

Tags: google-app-engine, java-11

Google is deprecating Java 8 on Google App Engine.  There seems to be no support for IDEs in moving to Java 11.  The Google Cloud plugin for Eclipse is no longer supported.  Google says Google Cloud Code will no longer support Java 11 on IntelliJ.

How does one go about debugging a GAE app locally?

We used to use Eclipse with the Google Cloud plugin.  Worked very nicely for debugging locally.

Newer versions of the Google CLI have a local server so that GAE apps can be run locally.  But I don't see how to debug locally with it?  Does it integrate with any IDE?

Answer (score 1):

According to this documentation on [supported Java versions](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/supported-java-versions#keeping_production_systems_current):

> Java 8 will continue to be supported by Cloud Client Libraries for Java until at least September 2026.

You can still use Eclipse in deploying and debugging GAE apps locally based on this documentation for [GAE standard](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/running-and-debugging) and [flexible](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/deploy-jetty). [Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart) currently supports JDK 8 or 11 only. Earlier or later versions are not yet supported.

You can also use run and debug GAE apps locally on [Cloud Code for IntelliJ](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/deploy-local) for GAE standard only.

Another debugging option would be **Snapshot Debugger** that is available for both [Java 8](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/snapshot-debugger/tree/main/samples/java/appengine-java8) and [11](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/snapshot-debugger/tree/main/samples/java/appengine-java11) and other variety of languages.

Comment: I believe the link to GAE Standard is old.  GAE is not suspported with the Google Cloud Plugin for Eclipse with Java 11.  There is no way to run the local app-engine dev server as a Java 11 dev server.  I guess you can run the server locally in Java 8 and hope it works when deployed to GAE in Java 11.  As for the Cloud Code Plugin, this web page (https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/create-standard) sas only Java 8 is supported for app engine standard environment.

Comment: Just checked out Snapshot Debugger.  It is not a source level debugger.  At this point it seems like Google has left developers in the lurch.  I guess we can debug using logs and snapshot debugger, but that's like going back 30 years in software development.