# How to use Snapshot Debugger on Google App Engine

Tags: debugging, google-app-engine, snapshot

I have a webhook issue with code written in PHP on Google App Engine that is very difficult to debug. The webhook doesn't have a frontend, so to diagnose the issue I'm in a "print to syslog and redeploy to App Engine" debug cycle which is very slow. Unfortunately, the bug only appears on a production server, not local or staging servers, so my debug options are limited.

Google had a snapshot debugger to diagnose issues on a running server, but has deprecated the service. The announcement is here https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/deprecations/debugger-deprecation and says "...it remains available to use." How do I do that on App Engine? Is it really still possible to use? All documentation and support seems to have disappeared.

For reference, the original PHP debugger is on GitHub here, but the documentation links point back to Google's deprecation announcement. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-debugger

Comment: Can you have a look at this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76885580/18265702).

Comment: `Unfortunately, the bug only appears on a production server, not local or staging servers, so my debug options are limited.` Do you mean you are able to deploy locally and is working fine and facing issues only on the appengine?

Comment: I'm able to deploy locally and a staging instance of appengine. Unfortunately there's something different about the data in the production webhook that doesn't happen in staging instances. This is the reason a snapshot debugger would help. The bug causes the instance to _occasionally_ hang rather than answer the webhook. Ironically when I reduced the amount of prints to syslog it stopped the issue, so now think the problem is buried in how Google implements logging.

Comment: Can you try [enabling debug mode](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/debugging-an-instance#enabling_and_disabling_debug_mode) of an instance and writing logs to the system. Also try using [debug in logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/go111/writing-application-logs#:~:text=levels%20of%20severity%3A-,Debug,-Warning).  Have a look at this  [Reading and Writing Application Logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/php/logs).